# Comparing two servers Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two Windows Server 2008, Server A and B. Both ones have exact same hardware and same O/S version. However, server A is slower than server B. How do I realize that? For example, if I have to unzip a zip file of 1GB, in server A this task takes double time than in server B.

I can only think that there is some program in server A that makes it slower.

However, if I run "resmon", it shows that server A is consuming 8% of memory and server B 9%.

[image]

So, what could be making server A to be slow?

How could I compare what programs have server A and B?

Would be OK for both servers to list installed programs or to list services? Would be there a way to list both things?

---

### EDIT:

I compared services between them, and they have almost the same. Few services in Server A that were not running in Server B, were disabled. Also, I run last Windows updates for both servers.

Still, server A is slower than Server B.

However, comparing taskmanager processes I realized that server A has more processes than B.

Server A has more processes like: 
cmd.exe, cpqteam.exe, csrss.exe, dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.e , dwm.exe, mmc.exe, wuauclt.exe. Those processes exist in both servers, but A has more of them.

There is one process in server A that does not appear in Server B:

msiexec.exe

Could it mean something?

Comment: Is the antivirus different on the servers?  Also try copying the file to a different name so that it is on a different part of the disk.  Then try the unzip.

Comment: There's no antivirus on both servers, because they are going to be database servers.

Comment: taskmanager would let you see what you need in this case.

Comment: Unrelated, but it's still a good idea to run an AV on database servers, just exclude the database files.

Comment: when you do the unzip compare the cpu's within taskmanager are the percentages used equal or not, if not what other process are running during the unzip.

Comment: unzip is disk intensive so what are the disks subsystems like?

Answer (score 1):

Start with Process Explorer from Microsoft's SysInternals.  This'll give you more info than resmon.  I'd then be using Performance Monitor to watch physical disk busy time and queue length, CPU utilisation and paging activity.  You can monitor both servers from one instance of perfmon.  Kick off the same task on both servers and see what's different.  Also, what's the commit charge on both servers?  Are the paging files the same size?

Comment: Both servers have the same paging size.